# excel/VBA pass a sheetname to a function

Tags: excel, vba, macros, basic

i have few sheet, and a need for once of it that a specific cell (A1) is equal "1" the label color become green once the change their value.

I declare in a ThisWorkBook the following function:

```
Public Function ColorLabel(LabelName)
Set Foglio = Sheets(LabelName)
Set Target = Foglio.Range("A1")

If Target = "1" Then
    Foglio.Tab.ColorIndex = 4
Else
    Foglio.Tab.ColorIndex = xlNone
end if
End Function
```

So, in every sheet i define the following code

```
Private function Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 ColorLabel(ActiveSheet.CodeName)
end function
```

but I get the following error

> Compilation error. Expected variable or routine and not form

What's wrong?

Someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You should insert a `new` module and place your code in there, rather than the `ThisWorkbook` module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function is defined in the `ThisWorkbook` module, you should call it this way:

```
    ThisWorkbook.ColorLabel Me.Name
```

and by the way, as it is written, ColorLabel shoud be a Sub not a function (it does not return anything).

However, better design would be:

- move the sub to an independent code module
  or
- rename the sub into an event handler using `Workbook_SheetChange`

Answer (score 1):

Your `Public Function ColorLabel(LabelName)` should be placed in a `Module`, not inside one of the `Sheets` or the `Workbook`. Usualy we place there code that is related only to `Sheets` events or `Workbook` events.

*see image for `Public Function ColorLabel(LabelName)` code*

[image]

Your `Private function Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` should be in the `Workbook_SheetChange` event (in the `Workbook` module):

[image]

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

ColorLabel (Sh.Name)

End Sub
```

---

You could improve your code, by not calling `ColorLabel` function on every change made to any cell in any sheet, by checking if the `Target` is inside `Range("A1")`, see code below:

**Improved Code:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

' call the ColorLabel function only if value in Cell A1 was modified
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    ColorLabel (Sh.Name)
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to pass the name of the worksheet at all?  Just pass a reference to the worksheet itself:

```
Public Function ColorLabel(Foglio As Worksheet)
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = Foglio.Range("A1")

    If Target.Value = "1" Then
        Foglio.Tab.ColorIndex = 4
    Else
        Foglio.Tab.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
End Function

'If this is the event handler you want...

Private Function Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ColorLabel Me
End Function

'Or in ThisWorkbook:

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)    
    ColorLabel Sh     
End Sub
```